# Loading a script in my websites header

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the header of my website, I want to add the script for a slider. If I dont close the script, the slider works, but if i close it it stops working

it works if i let the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5slider.js">
```

if I close it the slider stops working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5slider.js"></script>
```

What could be the error?

Comment: Did you open your browser console to look at any errors?

Comment: What is your doctype? What is your JS code that initializes the slider? What does your markup look like? Are there any script errors in your browser console?

Comment: You need to show us more of your html. This question as is cannot be reasonably answered.

Comment: error is: [17:40:56.271] TypeError: $.when is not a function @ mysite/new/js/tms-0.4.1.js:965

Comment: row 965 is: $.when($('.'+_.bannerCl,.me)).then(function(){ $('.'+.bannerCl,.me).not(.banner).remove() }),

Answer (score 3):

Leaving out the end script tag causes the browser to ignore the script tag right *after* that one.

For example,

```
<script src="a.js">
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

b.js will not be loaded because the browser interprets its end tag to belong to a.js.

In other words, you have an error in the *next* script that's causing all scripts on the page to halt, including the slider. Look in the [error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: [17:40:56.271] TypeError: $.when is not a function @ mysite/new/js/tms-0.4.1.js:965

Comment: row 965 is: $.when($('.'+_.bannerCl,_.me)).then(function(){
         $('.'+_.bannerCl,_.me).not(_.banner).remove()
        }),